# My PHP PDO Class won't work

Tags: php, database, pdo

**Here is Database.php**:

```
<?php
/*Data Base Class
* MySQL - InnoDB 
* PHP - PDO (PHP Data Object -So we could change databases if needed)
*/
class Database extends PDO{
    private $DBH;

    function __construct($host, $dbname, $user, $pass){
        try {
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {  
            return $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }

    public function alteration_query($sql){
        /* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
        $this->DBH->beginTransaction();
        try{
            $count = $this->DBH->exec($sql);
            $this->DBH->commit();
            return $count;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
          $this->DBH->rollback();
          return  $e;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Here is test.php**:

```
<?php
require('Database.php');
$dbo = new Database('***.***.com','***','***','***');
echo $dbo->alteration_query('DELETE * from T_Table');
?>
```

For some reason, it won't give me an error or delete the contents of the T_table.

Comment: How do you know it's not giving an error? You're not checking for one.

Comment: Don't catch the exceptions inside of the class, catch them outside.

Comment: @Truth, but how will I know when to rollBack my actions?

Comment: @agam360: Rollback is done automatically on error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The problem in your case is that the argument is called `$sql`, but you're using `$query` to execute it (in the alteration_query method). Next time, please enable error reporting, and/or use a decent IDE, that can show you these errors. Like so:

[image: Example]

EDIT2: Set PDO's error mode to exception, this way any error would throw an exception. See updated code.

Don't catch your exceptions inside of the functions, do it outside:

```
<?php
/*Data Base Class
* MySQL - InnoDB 
* PHP - PDO (PHP Data Object -So we could change databases if needed)
*/
class Database
{
    private $DBH;

    function __construct($host, $dbname, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        //Set PDO to throw exceptions on errors!
        $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function alteration_query($sql)
    {
        /* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
        $this->DBH->beginTransaction();
        $count = $this->DBH->exec($query);
        $this->DBH->commit();
        return $count;
    }
}

try {
    $pdo = new Database("localhost", "dbname", "user", "pass");
    $pdo->alteration_query("SELECT * FROM wrong_table");
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("An error has occured! " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

This way, you can catch the error exactly where you need it, and not force it inside of the function (which kinda beats the point of the exception).

Also, from the manual:

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if
>   you have an outstanding transaction, **PDO will automatically roll it
>   back**. This is a safety measure to help avoid inconsistency in the
>   cases where the script terminates unexpectedly--**if you didn't
>   explicitly commit the transaction, then it is assumed that something
>   went awry, so the rollback is performed for the safety of your data**.

Exceptions halt the execution of the function, meaning the `commit()` never happens, and it rolls back.

Comment: I think the goal here was to avoid to write each exception everywhere.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: You don't write it everywhere, you write it once around the entire block of code you're **testing for exceptions** that's the **POINT OF EXCEPTIONS**, to throw them in case of an exception, and **catch** them WHENEVER YOU USE THE CODE.

Comment: I've noticed that (even edited my post before you did), and changed it (in my code), does not delete or ive an error yet :| (it returns a zero and that's it)

Comment: @agam360: See NOW. Now it catches the error (tested): `An error has occured! SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM \`wrong_table\`' at line 1`

Comment: @agam360: Also, this class does not extend PDO, it contains a PDO instance. You should learn the difference :)

Comment: Thanks, I made it delete the row, but the affected rows still shows zero, why is that?

Comment: @agam360: Your syntax is wrong you know, `DELETE FROM table` not `DELETE * FROM table`.

Comment: @Truth, Yes my bad, toda! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this line :

```
$this->DBH = new parent::__construct("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

Reason : __construct overwrite the main class function. I think that's why, really not sure.

If it's not working, try `parrent::PDO`. I am pretty sure it an overwrite problem.

Comment: It produces an error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

Comment: @agam360 That weird. On the line I gave you ? ... Check for space and UTF-8 byte inside your file, retype the line manually instead of CTRL-C/V.

Comment: What do you mean by retyping it? what could possibly go wrong with ctrl+v/c?